Created wallet v4 address does not match: TonConnectUI vs. Tonkeeper
I am creating a new Ton wallet address using the following code. It should be v4 address based on the API documentation of TonConnect:
import crypto from "@ton/crypto";
import {toUserFriendlyAddress} from "@tonconnect/ui";
import ton from "@ton/ton";

export async function makeV4Address(mnemonics) {
    const workchain = 0; // Usually you need a workchain 0
    const keyPair = await crypto.mnemonicToPrivateKey(mnemonics);
    const wallet = ton.WalletContractV4.create({ workchain, publicKey: keyPair.publicKey });    
    console.log(wallet);
    const rawFormat = `${workchain}:${wallet.publicKey.toString("hex")}`;
    return toUserFriendlyAddress(rawFormat);
}


//const mnemonics = await crypto.mnemonicNew();

// Hardcoded word list for testing - do not use this address
const mnemonics = `
circle
sword
pet
letter
door
woman
sure
cage
milk
uniform
eyebrow
quit
response
kitchen
learn
dumb
march
peanut
climb
deposit
claw
system
plastic
ship`.trim().split(/\r?\n/)


console.log("Mnemonics are:", mnemonics.join(" "));
const address = await makeV4Address(mnemonics);
console.log("Created address", address);

The created address is: UQClm0SeSxKQ5WSAw3xjT8skrzAsQrWoFET50KvGfoZ-tY-h
However this is different address from any of addresses TonKeeper gives in its version selector:


What causes the difference in addresses
How can I ensure mnemonics and addresses created programmatically are compatible with Ton wallets?


You're creating an address based on the public key that controls the wallet contract, not the address of the deployed wallet.
export async function makeV4Address(mnemonics) {
    const workchain = 0; // Usually you need a workchain 0
    const keyPair = await crypto.mnemonicToPrivateKey(mnemonics);
    const wallet = ton.WalletContractV4.create({ workchain, publicKey: keyPair.publicKey });    
    console.log(wallet);
    const rawFormat = `${workchain}:${wallet.publicKey.toString("hex")}`;
    return toUserFriendlyAddress(wallet.address.toRawString()); // change here

Will output
UQBfg1VcidHBC88HaNXxyZgl9PhK34J1PaPqCbjqEB72hISE

Which matches your TONKeeper address.
